# Tomcat8/Spring/JAX-RS - Is it safe to have thread local variables in http-bio-8080-exec-XYZ threads?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, jax-rs, tomcat8

My stack is Tomcat8, with Spring and JAX-RS (Jersey) on top of it. This exposes a REST API to be used by the end user. In these REST endpoints, I need a socket connection to an ancient backend. It is costly to setup and destrot these socket connections for every request. I am thinking to store the connection in a thread local variable.

To make this happen, we need the guarantee that the *http-bio-8080-exec-[identifier]* threads will never be killed. If this is the case, we end up with a dangling socket connection which never will be closed. Eventually, we will out of available sockets (memory leak).

I have been going through several documentations, but couldn't find anything useful. So my question: will the thread pool behind the *http-bio-8080-exec-[identifier]* threads only grow, or will it also shrink?

Another option is to introduce a good-old object pool which holds the socket connections, but I thought a thread local approach would be better, as every REST request need that socket connection, so the size of the pool would be the same as the number of http workers. Is this a good reason to use thread locals instead of an object pool, in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it isn't documented to be safe then you cannot assume it is, or at least it could change between Tomcat versions.

The number of threads that Tomcat creates depends on the load on your application.  The maximum number is configurable, and I do think it goes down as well when load reduces.

However, you could use a Filter that gets a Socket (an existing one from a pool or new one) at the start of each request and set that in a ThreadLocal (or since you're using Spring, a Request scoped bean).  When the request ends, your Filter returns the Socket to the pool for re-use.